# Batch File - How do I display a precent of a variable?

Tags: batch-file, math

I have a batch file which must be able to display a percentage. Unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish this.

The file takes a range of individual points from 0 to 29 and adds or subtracts points from this range in a background process the user never sees. I want the current percent of how full that range is to be displayed. IE if there are 29 points the file displays "100 %", if there are 22 points it lists "75 %", ectra.

Mathematically the operation should be (x/29)*100. I have coded this operation as:

```
set /a math="%shields%" / "%scap%"
set /a sm="%math%" * 100
```

but my code dose not function. sm is the variable which will be the percent, shields is the current 0 - 29 point value and scap is the maximum value shields can be (normally 29 but some conditions can adjust this.)

Can I get a hand with this please? Its confusing.

Comment: when doing integer math, multiply first, divide only after you did multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matematic operation in bat don't accept floating point value if you make :
`22/29` in bat you'll get 0 and `0 *100 = 0`.

so you have to do `(x*100)/29`

```
@echo off
set $val=22
set /a $percent=(%$val%*100)/29
echo %$percent% %%
```